# CSS rule isn't being applied

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to apply this CSS rule:

```
.question.paragraph .question_choices li:nth-of-type(1)
 {
  padding-bottom: 500px;
}
```

It works in the console: `$(".question.paragraph .question_choices li:nth-of-type(1)").css("padding-bottom", "500px")`. [It works in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9NtCC/). It doesn't work in the browser. I'm in Google Chrome so the `nth-of-type` pseudoclass sbould be recognized. I checked the user-agent. I'm not in IE mode. Here's the (simplified) HTML:

```
<html class="no-js" lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->
  <head>
      <style type="text/css" media="screen" id="study_custom_style_applier">
        .question.paragraph .question_choices li:nth-of-type(1)
         {
          padding-bottom: 500px;
        }
      </style>
  </head>
  <body style="margin-left: 300px;">
    <div id="plain-container" style="margin-top: 128px;">
      <div id="body">
        <div class="question  paragraph" id="question_211681">
          <span class="question_label">p6_q1_Topic_2</span>
          <div class="question_title">
            Topic 2
          </div>
          <div class="question_choices">
            <ul>
                <li>stuff1</li> <!-- the rule should apply here - there should be 500px of bottom padding -->
                <li>stuff2</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

As far as I know, nothing is overriding the rule:

[image]

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: It looks like `#survey li { padding: 0 5px; }` is overriding it. Am I missing something?

Comment: Send the online link.

Comment: OT, micro-optimization: `ul` element can only have `li` children so you can safely replace `:nth-of-type()` by `:nth-child()`

Comment: @Eric thanks, that's probably it! I thought my rule is more specific than `#survey li` though? How do I rewrite it then?

Comment: @ilikepie Because of the nature of IDs, they're more specific than... well, pretty much everything except `!important` and inline styles. I've provided some possible solutions in an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As far as I know, nothing is overriding the rule:
>
> [image]

Actually, it looks like it *is* being overridden. Based on your screenshot, it looks to me like you have the following rule in one of your CSS files:

```css
#survey li {
    padding: 0 5px;
}
```

Because of [CSS specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/), the `#survey` ID reference is overriding your `.question.paragraph` class reference.

## Solutions

You haven't showed the whole HTML in your post, so I can only guess what your `#survey` tag is. The solution depends on your implementation. Try **one** of the following:

1. Adding to `#survey` a `survey` *class*, and then using `.survey li`, which *should* fix it.

   ```css
    .survey li { padding: 0 5px; }
   ```
2. Prepending your `nth-of-type` rule with `#survey`.

   ```css
    #survey .question.paragraph .question_choices li:nth-of-type(1) { ... }
   ```
3. Appending `!important` to your `padding-bottom` rule.

   ```css
    ... { padding-bottom: 500px !important; }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions

1) Add !important after the rule to override any conflicts.

```
.question.paragraph .question_choices li:nth-of-type(1)
 {
  padding-bottom: 500px !important;
}
```

2) Whatever browser you're using doesn't support the pseudo CSS3 class selector :nth-of-type. You could try adding the style inline or use jQuery as you showed in your question on document load.

```
$(".question.paragraph .question_choices li:nth-of-type(1)").css("padding-bottom", "500px")
```